# Can i revert back to syncdb after installing SOUTH

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I installed SOUTH and migrated few apps. now i want to go back to syncDB and uninstall SOUTH.
Can i go back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- Stop your server.
- First, **backup your database** to be on
  the safe side.
- Execute:

  `./manage.py sqlclear south | ./manage.py dbshell`

  (this is
  probably buggy on windows.  Use copy
  and paste instead of the pipe.)
- Remove south from your
  `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.